# Не срабатывает слот в Qt с QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt, сигналы-слоты, qpushbutton

Хай. Пишу таймер. Есть QPushButton, создающиеся в цикле "+" и "-" , отвечающие за настройку часов/минут/секунд.

Привязал слот `connect(minus, SIGNAL(QPushButton::clicked()), this, SLOT(mainTime::editTime(i)));`. Слот не срабатавыет, но компилятор не ругается.

Хедер:

```
#pragma once
#include <qwidget.h>
#include <qapplication.h>

class mainTime :public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT;
public:
    mainTime(QWidget* parent = 0);

public slots:
    void editTime(int index);

};
```

Цикл:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    QPushButton* plus = new QPushButton("+"); 
    connect(plus, SIGNAL(QPushButton::clicked()), this, SLOT(mainTime::editTime(i)));
    QPushButton* minus = new QPushButton("-");
    connect(minus, SIGNAL(QPushButton::clicked()), this, SLOT(mainTime::editTime(i)));
}
```

Сам слот:

```
void mainTime::editTime(int index) {
    if (!tmr->isActive()) {
        int get = timeList->at(index)->text().toInt();
        timeList->at(index)->setText(normalise(buttonText == "+" ? (++get % 60) : (60 + (--get)) % 60));
    }
};
```

Вроде делаю точно также, как везде, а работать не хочет. Что подскажете?
(Это не из-за if в функции)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. Хм, а как связаны ваши plus и minus с интерфейсом? 2. Таким образом передать i нельзя

Comment: Предвосхищая следующий вопрос, `i` можно передать или с помощью `QSignalMapper`, если использовать олдскульные `SLOT`'ы, или через лямбды, если на столе новомодный С++11+

Comment: @Fat-Zer, спасибо за QSignalMapper. Теперь все работает